# How to install Kubernetes v1.10.11 on a GCP cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

There was recently a Kubernetes security hole that was patched in v1.10.11 (among other versions), so I would like to upgrade to that version. I am currently on v1.10.9. However, when running the command `gcloud container get-server-config` to get the list of valid node versions, v1.10.11 doesn't show up. Instead, it jumps straight from v1.10.9 to v1.11.2.

Does anyone have any idea why I cannot seem to use the usual `gcloud container clusters upgrade [CLUSTER_NAME] --cluster-version [CLUSTER_VERSION]` to upgrade to this version?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Based on:

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/security-bulletins#december-3-2018

If you have Kubernetes in `v1.10.9` you should (to patch this security hole) update your GKE Cluster to `1.10.9-gke.5.`

```
The following Kubernetes versions are now available for new clusters and for opt-in master upgrades for existing clusters:

1.9.7-gke.11,
1.10.6-gke.11,
1.10.7-gke.11,
1.10.9-gke.5,
1.11.2-gke.18
```

Please validate your `Scheduled master auto-upgrades` option in GKE. 
If it's enabled your cluster masters were auto-upgraded by Google and the next possible version to update is further version so `v1.11.2`, what is showing by GKE for you.